# Comparing two column family in cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have two huge column family TABLE-A and TABLE-B 
Now I am checking to see if both the column family are identical or not.

Also, I want to return the mismatch. Is there any way in Cassandra to achieve this?

Comment: short answer - no. cassandra isn't built for this kind of analytics. You'll be better off with a separate tool like spark

Answer (score 1):

For such use case you might want to have a look at [Spark cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

You can create 2 Dataframe/Dataset and then compare the data using maybe `df1.except(df2)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try and use `sstabledump` and do a programmatic comparison of the output (which will probably be huge)